# How to generate messagebox on client side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, winapi, messagebox

Hii all, 
          In my Ruby code am able to generate messagebox but i would like to know how to see it at client side ,am running rails application means server is running on my machine and tha messagebox is also generating on my machine but am nor able not abble to see it client side anyone has any idea how to do that in ruby??

Comment: I think is not system in web design too.

Comment: what do u mean shingara it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I got your question not right, but isn't it a typically JavaScript-Alert case? ;)

```
alert("I am a message box with an ok button.");
```

Or did I get it wrong?

---

### Edit

If you're using Rails 3 at least it's:

```
javascript_tag "alert('All is good')"
```

Comment: shevron i am trying to something like that but how do i call it from ruby